# $("#signInModal").modal('hide'); not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I trying to hide modal after login success by call ajax
But I cannot use $("#signInModal").modal('hide'); ($().modal is not a function. i don't understand how it work, I use bootstrap 4 's modal. How can l use this or the other way to hide modal @@
i really use it ontop, and I cannot use it again.Please help me @@

here is my code

```
  $("#signUpButton").on('click', function () {
    $("#signInModal").modal('hide');
  })
})(jQuery);
// //validate password on login event
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login").submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
        var txtUsername = $("#exampleInputEmail1");
        var txtPassword = $("#logInPassword");
        
        var username=txtUsername.val().trim();
        var password=txtPassword.val().trim();
        console.log(username);
        console.log(password);
        if( username != "" && password != "" ){
            $.ajax({
                url:'login.php',
                type:'Post',
                data:{username:username,password:password},
                success:function(response){
                    var msg = "";
                    console.log(response);
                    if(response == 1){
                      $("#signInModal").modal('hide');
                        console.log(response);
                    }else{
                        msg = "Invalid username and password!";
                    }
                    if (!strIsEmpty(msg)) {
                      console.log(msg);
                      return;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: please check that jquery modal script defined and initialized before using

Comment: use bootstrap.js too

Comment: And don't use nested or chained `$(document).ready()`s.

Comment: What JS files are you including on the page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you included js in the footer of the page. Please call the function after it.